# Jasmine/Angular: Testing the reception of a void EventEmitter onInit?

Tags: angular, jasmine

I'm writing unit testing for one of my components. Said component has a `visible` boolean, initialized as false. When said boolean property becomes true, the component's display css attribute goes from none to block, making it visible.

Since my component is a child component, the cycle that I built so that a parent component technically 'triggers' the component is the following:

- The component initializes in an insivible state. Both the parent and the child are connected to a Service looking like this:

```
    export class SidebarService {

    public toggleSidebar: EventEmitter<void> = new EventEmitter();
    
      constructor() {}

    public showSidebar() {
       this.toggleSidebar.emit();
      }
    }
```

The service does not require connection to any endpoints nor does it return any data: the emitter acts as a 'one-time-per-click' signal to the child component.

- Clicking a button in the parent template, the parent calls the following method:

```
 toggleSidebar() {
    this.sidebarService.showSidebar();
  }
```

- On my child component's OnInit, I wrote the following:

```
     ngOnInit() {
        this.sidebarService.toggleSidebar.subscribe(() => {
          this.visible = true;
        });
      }
```

So that when the parent triggers the event emitter, the child receives it and changes its `visible` property. The child component has its own manual method to reset the visible property to false.

From a functional perspective, it does the job: the component 'appears' when the parent component clicks the button. But now I fear I might have botched the 'connectivity' aspect of their relation.

When writing the unit test, what I have so far for the component is the following:

```
describe('FilterSidebarComponent', () => {
  let component: FilterSideBarComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<FilterSideBarComponent>;

  const sidebarServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('SidebarService', [
    'showSidebar'
  ]);

  const fb: FormBuilder = new FormBuilder();

  configureTestSuite(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        MockModule(FormsModule),
        MockModule(ReactiveFormsModule),
        MockModule(TranslateModule.forRoot())
      ],
      declarations: [
        FilterSideBarComponent,
        CheckboxInputComponent,
        MockComponent(CountrySingleSearchComponent),
        MockComponent(UniversitiesSearcherComponent)
      ],
      providers: [
        {provide: SidebarService, useValue: sidebarServiceSpy},
        {provide: FormBuilder, useValue: fb},
      ]
    });
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FilterSideBarComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

And the only test written so far ('should create'), fails, with Jasmine telling me:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
at 
at FilterSideBarComponent.subscribe [as ngOnInit]

I have searched for similar topics in StackOverflow regarding ways of mocking the subscription of services, but all examples I have found use services that return objects, data or Observables.

Of course I can rewrite the Service as long as it conserves its function, but- is there an effective way to test a 'Service' like mine, or should I rewrite the service in some way?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're subscribing to the toggleSidebar property which isn't defined in your mock service.  I'm not sure Jasmine supports mocking properties so I would just create a mock object something like the below.  When you want to trigger your event for testing you'd then do sideBarSubject.next().

Also I don't believe it is recommended to use EventEmitters in services.  I would change your service to use a Subject as well.

If you later need to spy on your new mock sidebar service you can do spyOn(sidebarServiceSpy, 'showSideBar') which is necessary because you're no longer creating it as a spy to begin with.

```
describe('FilterSidebarComponent', () => {
  let component: FilterSideBarComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<FilterSideBarComponent>;


  let sideBarSubject = new Subject<void>();
  const sidebarServiceSpy = {
    toggleSidebar = sideBarSubject;
    showSidebar: Function(){}
  }

  const fb: FormBuilder = new FormBuilder();

  configureTestSuite(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        MockModule(FormsModule),
        MockModule(ReactiveFormsModule),
        MockModule(TranslateModule.forRoot())
      ],
      declarations: [
        FilterSideBarComponent,
        CheckboxInputComponent,
        MockComponent(CountrySingleSearchComponent),
        MockComponent(UniversitiesSearcherComponent)
      ],
      providers: [
        {provide: SidebarService, useValue: sidebarServiceSpy},
        {provide: FormBuilder, useValue: fb},
      ]
    });
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FilterSideBarComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: The solution didn't quite work, but I am still giving it  a 'thumbs up' not only because of the good intent but because you are right: using an EventEmitter for this was probably not just not recommended, but a bit nonsensical too. If I just wanted to pass a signal between a parent component and a child, using an Input() property was more tan enough for me.

BUT, for future occasions, I will give your suggestion (using Subjects instead of eventEmitters) a shot, in case that I do need to receive data or Observables from my service. Thanks!